# Distributed tensorflow: non chief worker stuck at starter session

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I have two workers and a parameter server. The chief worker works well, but the non chief worker stuck at this line of code

```
with sv.managed_session(server.target, config=config) as sess, sess.as_default():
```

and produce output as follows:

```
[2017-01-06 21:24:40,954] Starting session. If this hangs, we're mostly    likely waiting to connect to the parameter server. One common cause is that the parameter server DNS name isn't resolving yet, or is misspecified.
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:928] Start master session 67667d6cd148265a with config:
device_filters: "/job:ps"
device_filters: "/job:worker/task:1/cpu:0"

I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:928] Start master session 1c4e0742ba99e5ea with config:
device_filters: "/job:ps"
device_filters: "/job:worker/task:1/cpu:0"

I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:928] Start  master session 9575940608a24fcd with config:
device_filters: "/job:ps"
device_filters: "/job:worker/task:1/cpu:0"
```

It start master session again and again.

train supervisor is set as follows:

```
def init_fn(ses):
    logger.info("Initializing all parameters.")
    ses.run(init_all_op)

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_filters=["/job:ps", "/job:worker/task:{}/cpu:0".format(args.worker_id)]) # refer to worker id
logdir = os.path.join(args.log_dir, 'train')
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logdir + "_%d" % args.worker_id)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(args.worker_id == 0),
                         logdir=logdir,
                         saver=saver,
                         summary_op=None,
                         init_op=init_op,  # Defaults to an Operation that initializes all variables
                         init_fn=init_fn,
                         summary_writer=summary_writer,
                         ready_op=tf.report_uninitialized_variables(variables_to_save),
                         global_step=trainer.global_step[target_task],
                         save_model_secs=30,
                         save_summaries_secs=30)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

#### update

quote from tensorflow documentation:

> In the chief task, the Supervisor works exactly as in the first example above. In the other tasks sv.managed_session() waits for the Model to have been initialized before returning a session to the training code. The non-chief tasks depend on the chief task for initializing the model.
>
> If one of the tasks crashes and restarts, managed_session() checks if the Model is initialized. If yes, it just creates a session and returns it to the training code that proceeds normally. If the model needs to be initialized, the chief task takes care of reinitializing it; the other tasks just wait for the model to have been initialized.

The distributed approach I used here is *Between-graph replication*, The reason is I defined two graphs in a workers, one of them is not complete. and I try to complete that graph in non-chief worker. Therefore it crash at managed_session() and restart. This problem is fixed when I define two graphs in chief worker completely.

Comment: Are you executing your `sv.managed_session` line over and over again by chance? BTW, full reproducible example is useful to answer these questions